# Hide Custom Shipping When Multiple Items are in cart

Tags: woocommerce

I added a plugin that creates a shipping method with Id "pisol_extended_flat_shipping:52540" when the product category is "baby-care" and the country is "India" and It's working fine. When someone adds different products from different categories in the cart and one of the categories is "baby-care". then I want to hide the "pisol_extended_flat_shipping:52540" shipping when there are other category products at the checkout along with "baby-care".

I tried this code, but not working

```
function check_cart_categories() {
$baby_care = false;
$other_categories = false;
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
$product = $cart_item['data'];
if ( has_term( 'baby-care', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {
$baby_care = true;
} else {
$other_categories = true;
}
}
return ( $baby_care && $other_categories );
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_shipping_methods', 'hide_pisol_extended_flat_shipping' );
function hide_pisol_extended_flat_shipping( $available_methods ) {
if ( check_cart_categories() ) {
unset( $available_methods['pisol_extended_flat_shipping:52540'] );
}
return $available_methods;
}
```

Comment: The filter `woocommerce_available_shipping_methods` does not exist, did you get that hook from an outdated source? 
You can use `woocommerce_package_rates` instead. Here are some working examples which you can use: 
https://woocommerce.com/document/hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available/

Comment: Thank you for the response. I checked the link you provided, but I couldn't find how can I use it for my store, cause I am not a programmer, So If you can help with the complete code, I'll really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full code:

```
function check_cart_categories() {
    // your logic here...
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_pisol_extended_flat_shipping' , 10, 2 );

function hide_pisol_extended_flat_shipping( $rates, $package  ) {
    if ( check_cart_categories() ) {
        unset( $rates['pisol_extended_flat_shipping:52540'] );
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

If it doesn't work, try increasing the priority of the hook (I set default `10`). Some plugins are also using this hook and could interfere.

Comment: it worked on one of my websites, but it is not working on the other website, where the product category and shipping method is different(I changed the category and shipping id) :

Comment: The above code is not limited to your case, it should work everywhere. To debug, you should set the priority of the hook from `10` to `PHP_INT_MAX`. If this doesn't do the trick, you will need to disable the shipping cache in the settings and `var_dump()` each variable to find the problem.